# Laravel does not recognize trait

Tags: php, laravel-5, traits

I'm changing  **AuthenticatesUsers.php** to use google recaptcha in **postLogin** method.

Have a trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;

trait CaptchaTrait {
    public function captchaCheck()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and my `AuthenticatesUsers.php` starts with

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use App\Traits\CaptchaTrait;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;
    use CaptchaTrait;
...
}
```

In login page, I get this error

```
FatalErrorException in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 13: Trait
'App\Traits\CaptchaTrait' not found
```

Can't understand why. In PhpStorm when importing class **CaptchaTrait** it automatically import **App\Traits\CaptchaTrait** to **AuthenticatesUsers.php**

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is located your trait file ?

Comment: app/App/Traits/CaptchaTrait.php

Comment: However, it's a bad practise to modify the `vendor` files.

Comment: Thanks @pespantelis. Only testing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your composer.json file for more information on what the App namespace is.  It's a link to the app/ directory (PSR-4).

So the namespace App\Traits is equivalent to the directory app/Traits, not app/App/Traits.  The namespace and directories have to match what is defined in your composer autoloader, otherwise, it won't know how to load the class/trait/interface.